# Facebook share button - custom image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am trying to integrate facebook's share button into my page. I am using the following code:

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

This generates the image and the code for sharing. However I'm trying to use my own image for the share button. I am using the following code:

```
<a name="fb_share"><img src="fb.png" /></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

where fb.png is a custom image with the FB logo.

The problem is that my image shows along with the generic Facebook share image to the left... Do you know if there's a way to implement a custom image for the share button?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think FaceBook prohibits editing of it buttons. I wanted to do the same thing and gave up...

Answer (score 4):

You should do a trick like this:

**HTML**:

```
<a id='share'><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
    type="text/javascript"></script></a>
```

**CSS**:

```
#share *{
   filter:alpha(opacity=0.1); 
   opacity:0.01;/*Hide Facebook button*/
}

#share{
  display:inline-block;

  /*The width and height of your image. Not bigger than the Like button!*/
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  /*Your image*/
  background:url(fb.png);
}
```

Comment: Is "Not bigger than the like button" because the <script> sets the width/height of the clickable element? Could you use JQuery to overwrite that?

Comment: @Pro83: That's because the `Like` button has a fixed height and width; if the image is bigger than that, the part of the image that's outside the `Like` button won't trigger a _Like_. If necessary, you can place multiple buttons directly next to and below each other to cover the entire image.